# Data loss while shutting down hazelcast node

Tags: hazelcast

I have hazelcast configured for two nodes ( N1 & N2 ), out of which one(N1) is is in active mode & other node(N2) will be passive mode.
Active node (N1) fills data to the map. let say 5 records.
The same 5 records can be seen at N2 node.

When I shut down node N1, my N2 node becomes active . But at this time when I print the maps, it shows me less records (sometime 3 and sometime 4).

I am new to hazelcast. 
My map configuration is as given below. 
Please provide me right direction to fix the data loss.

Thanks
bsk

```
<in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>100000</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">100</max-size>
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy</merge-policy>
</map>
```

Comment: Hey, what Hazelcast version do you use? Can you try to remove all configuration and see if it still happens? Your shown configuration looks pretty standard, you don't have to configure that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. To my surprise, a restart of JVM solved the problem. Now it is working fine. I am using hazelcast 3.0.

Comment: You should certainly use a newer version. Hazelcast 3.0 is almost 3 years old. I strongly recommend to update to 3.6.x or at least 3.5.x.